# How to detect/filter empty string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

How do you filter empty cells in a column **in a form** of

`blank = ''
df = df[(df['Remarks']== blank)]`

please give me suggestion in the **given form** because i want to add multiple conditions using & or |. I tried this and the output was an error.

Comment: What is your error? Please provide full traceback and a **[mcve]**.

Comment: it didnt show any error. It just didnt filter the blank cells.

Comment: Please don't include links / images. These aren't helpful. Instead, see **[How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your columns aren't actually blank, but are nan/null.

Try the following;

```
df = df[df['Remarks'].isnull()]
```

I've removed the parenthesis from your example because you don't need to enclose a single conditional, only when you are passing multiple conditions, as such;

```
df = df[(df['Remarks']isnull()) & (df['Remarks'] == 'Some Value')]
```

Comment: the .isnull() is working. However, what if i want to say it is equal to not null?

Comment: solved! just use .notnull() series

Comment: Exactly like so. Also if you do need to check an if statement is False, you can insert a '~' before the statement like so;

`df = df[(df['Remarks']isnull()) & (~df['Remarks'] == 'Some Value')]`

This checks that the value is null, and that the value does NOT equal 'Some Value'

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what type of data you have, as you havent posted anything here. 
But may be you need to convert your columns to string using str and then do comparision
try this

```
blank = ''
df = df[(df['Remarks'].str == blank)]
```

Comment: Hi I have updated the question with the link of the picture of the csv

Comment: pictures are discouraged! Make it easier for everyone to use your data